# %5E being inserted into reverse url

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having a problem with a url resolving as it should. It's resolving as

http://localhost:8000/%5Ewebsites/?value=1&id=1 when it should be resolving as
http://localhost:8000/websites/?value=1&id=1

I've got the following urls.py inside of an app.

```
app_name = 'websites'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', website_views.homepage, name="homepage"), 
    url(r'^blog/$', website_views.blog, name="blog"),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<id>\d+)/$', website_views.blogpost, name="blogpost"),

]
```

I've got this inside of my project urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^websites/', include('websites.customerurls')),
```

The link that is resolving incorrectly is this:

```
<a href="{% url 'websites:homepage' %}?value=1&id=1" target="_blank">
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It parses the `^` as a real character (`%5e` maps to `^`).

Comment: Are you sure you did *not* escape the `^`? (like `\^`)?

Comment: Escape the ^ where?

Comment: in the `urlpatterns` where you did the `include(..)`.

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. Now this is weird. I deleted the ^ from the url(r'^websites/', include('websites.customerurls')). The url now resolves in the EXACT SAME way (i.e. it includes %5E), but the page now loads correctly. I'm baffled....

Comment: then there is perhaps another element in the url hierarchy that places the `^` in front. Is there anything that is higher up in the "tree" than the `urlpatterns` of the include. Somehow, the url contains such `^`. Although now it works, I think it is better to find the cause of this, since it does not generate nice URLs, and furthermore it is better to know why strange things happen in a webserver.

Comment: I got it figured out. I have to delete the ^  in urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^websites/', include('websites.customerurls')),. It now resolves without the %5E and the page loads correctly. Django is weird. lol.

Comment: no no! don't run the website without it, try adding whatever at the beginning, you will see it still works. it's not recommended

Comment: I'm only in development. S'all good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to delete the ^ in urlpatterns = [ url(r'^websites/', include('websites.customerurls')),. It now resolves without the %5E and the page loads correctly.

Comment: Do you run the website without the `^`?

Comment: add the `^` back, clear your browser cache and everything will be ok

Comment: @Lemayzeur, Correct. This is what I did :)